# Edit rejected for "attempting to address author" when it didn't seem to?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

Someone suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12271736) on one of my answers. While small, it clarifies an edge case in a useful way, and I appreciate it. Before I could see it and accept it myself, though, it was rejected by three different reviewers for the reason "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

Am I missing something? This reason seems blatantly wrong.

Comment: It was something that should have been a comment on the post. That way, you could have just added it yourself. Does that clarify anything for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When reviewers generally see edits that incorporate new and additional information into an edit of an answer, we often react as if this particular addition is attempting to put words in the answerer's mouth.  While a bit more critical reading would prevent this, the immediate gut reaction is to assume that the editor meant to leave a comment here asking the answerer to clarify.

This has indeed led to rejected reviews in which it makes *good* sense to allow this edit to go through, since the intent of the edit made it such that what was there wasn't really a comment, but rather that it enhanced the actual content.

It's not that it's blatantly wrong, but it is a bit of an overreaction.  Given the alternative of not reacting at *all* when this happens, we may get edits which introduce all kinds of information which the OP had no intention of adding.

To that end, if you feel like it should belong, go ahead and add it in.  It's kind of a bummer that the anonymous person wouldn't get any form of credit for it, but at the bare minimum, the information trying to be clarified isn't lost.